# Reference file for accdb file

Tags: vba, reference, ms-access-2010

I have access 2010 and the file extension for files created is accdb.
when i punch the below code from Excel VBA, it says "unrecognized file format"
I have added reference Microsoft DAO 3.6 object library
could anyone tell what reference am i actually supposed to add in Excel.

```
Sub dbinsert()
Dim DB As DAO.Database
Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
Set DB = DAO.OpenDatabase("D:\tblImport.accdb")
End sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not DAO 3.6 but the *Microsoft Office xx.0 Access database engine Object Library*.